# Mixed-data sampling (MIDAS) in R

Tags: r

I would like to analyze data which is sampled at different frequencies. There is a concept developed by Ghysels called Mixed-data sampling (MIDAS). I tried to find some functions or packages in R applying this method, but could't find anything. Does anybody know any function or package in R for this concept?

Comment: There is a new [midasr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/midasr/index.html) package.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you! Great!!!!